# Variance of the exponential hitting time of a random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales, stopping-times

Let $\left(S_n\right)_{n\geq 0}$ be a symmetric random walk on integers starting at 0. Fix a positive integer $a$, and define $\tau=\min\{n\geq 0:|S_{n}|=a\}$. How could we compute the variance $Var\left(e^{-\tau}\right)$? I thought that the hitting time $|S_n|=a$ suggests using the quadratic martingale $S_{n}^2-n$, but trying to construct a 'product martingale' by normalizing terms $e^{-S_n^2+S_{n-1}^2}$ wasn't particularly fruitful. Also, I am aware of the way to compute $\mathbb{P}\left(\tau=2k-1\right)$ for each $k$ but I couldn't find an obvious modification that gives the variance (and directly calculating the variance using the probabilities would be too complicated). Any hints or insights are appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an exponential, so it would be nice to use the exponential martingale! Note that if you write $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$, then for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\mathbb{E} \left ( e^{t S_n} \right ) = \mathbb{E} \left ( e^{t X_1} \right )^n = \cosh^n t,
$$
and thus, by independence, $M_n = e^{t S_n} (\cosh t)^{-n}$ is a martingale. This martingale stopped at $\tau$ is bounded, so the optional stopping theorem applies without issue, and therefore
$$
\mathbb{E} \left ( e^{t S_{\tau}} (\cosh t)^{- \tau} \right ) = 1.
$$
By symmetry, $S_{\tau}$ is independent of $\tau$ and is $\pm a$ with probability $1/2$, so you get that
$$
\mathbb{E}((\cosh t)^{-\tau}) = \frac{1}{\cosh (t a)}.
$$
Now, if you take $t$ such that $\cosh t = e$, you get $\mathbb{E}(e^{-\tau})$, and similarly to get the second moment and the variance.

Comment: Ahh setting $\sinh t=e$ was what I was missing. Thank you for saving my sanity! Just one minor question - wouldn't the expectation be $\cosh^{n} t$, or am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed, thanks, all the $\sinh$ should be $\cosh$, I'll fix this!

Comment: Sorry for another question, but could you please elaborate a bit on why $S_{\tau}$ and $\tau$ are independent? Thanks again!

Comment: It's because it's a simple symmetric random walk, so $S_{\tau} = \pm a$ with probability $1/2$, and informally, there is no reason that either of the two options would mean a longer or shorter waiting time. To be more precise, in terms of conditional distributions:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\tau \in \cdot | S_{\tau} = a) = \mathbb{P}(\tau \in \cdot | - S_{\tau} = -a) = \mathbb{P}(\tau \in \cdot | S_{\tau} = - a),
$$
where the last equality is the fact that $S$ and $-S$ have the same distribution and the same hitting time of $|a|$. Note that none of this works if you do not assume symmetric or simple.